# Stripe create payment intent giving type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, typeerror, payment

I am trying to create a react and node app that uses stripe payments. When I try to run it, it gives a type error in the create payment intent post method.

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntent.create({
                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based off the node docs for creating a payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create), it looks like you forgot an "s". Should be stripe.paymentIntents not stripe.paymentIntent.